# Is the following a Polish space

Tags: functional-analysis

Is $(C(2^\mathbb{N}))^\mathbb{N}$ a Polish space when viewed with the product topology? I ask because I am reading a proof which says that this is apparently true, but I'm not sure if it is.

Comment: What is $C(2^\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: Continuous functions from the Cantor set to $\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the uniform norm, maybe? If this is the case, $C(2^{\mathbb{N}})$ is itself a polish space, and since countable products of polish spaces are polish, your claim follows.